# How to resolve Apache2 restart error setting up config hosting for linode project

Tags: server, ssh, apache2, hosting

I set up a server for hosting sites eventually on linode. Using linux mint. Created a super user and added my other user not_root. Set up chrisbodnarchuk.com.conf. Had to restart apache and got below error. Apache2 is not running at all. This is apache on my ssh not my main machine.

```
not_root@grendeldServer:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ ls
000-default.conf  chrisbodnarchuk.com.conf  default-ssl.conf

not_root@grendeldServer:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ service apache2 reload
Failed to reload apache2.service: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
See system logs and 'systemctl status apache2.service' for details.

not_root@grendeldServer:/etc/apache2/sites-available$ systemctl status apache2.service
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
   └─apache2-systemd.conf
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-09-01 12:01:01 CDT; 6min ag
Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 4048 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILU
lines 1-7/7 (END)...skipping...
● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
   └─apache2-systemd.conf
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2017-09-01 12:01:01 CDT; 6min ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
Process: 4048 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
```

When i run sudo service apache2 reload i get

```
apache2.service is not active, cannot reload.
```

Also this

```
[Fri Sep 01 11:55:11.093487 2017] [core:warn] [pid 3790] AH00111: Config  variable ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR} is not defined
[Fri Sep 01 11:55:11.093766 2017] [core:warn] [pid 3790] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_PID_FILE} is not defined
[Fri Sep 01 11:55:11.093846 2017] [core:warn] [pid 3790] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_USER} is not defined
[Fri Sep 01 11:55:11.093913 2017] [core:warn] [pid 3790] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP} is not defined
[Fri Sep 01 11:55:11.094177 2017] [core:warn] [pid 3790] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
 [Fri Sep 01 11:55:11.097786 2017] [core:warn] [pid 3790:tid 139892600903552] AH00111: Config variable ${APACHE_LOG_DIR} is not defined
AH00526: Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
```

Not sure exactly where to begin to fix or if I should just reinstall Apache2 on the ssh else make a new user?

Comment: start here `Syntax error on line 74 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` please run `cat /etc/apache2/apache2.conf` and post it into your question.

Comment: Also a lot of config variables are not defined, maybe `/etc/apache2/envvars` is missing.

Comment: post output of `apachectl -t` that should let you know what the problem was.

Comment: thanks for the help everyone. I've yet to try it but I'll follow up once I'm back on that project.

Comment: after apachectl -t  `AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 45.79.149.90. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
(2)No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory '/var/www/html/chrisbodnarchuk.com/log/' for error log of vhost defined at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/chrisbodnarchuk.com.conf:4
AH00014: Configuration check failed
Action '-t' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.` @LasVegasCoder

Answer (score 0):

### Fixing apache error AH02291

Apachectl -t error.

> No such file or directory: AH02291: Cannot access directory
>   '/var/www/html/chrisbodnarchuk.com/log/' for error log of vhost
>   defined at /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/chrisbodnarchuk.com.conf:4
>   AH00014: Configuration check failed Action '-t' failed. The Apache
>   error log may have more information.

Two errors to fix:

1. Cannot access directory /var/www/html/chrisbodnarchuk.com/log/

   `mkdir -p /var/www/html/chrisbodnarchuk.com/log`
   The above will create log directory.

NOTE: if you defined a log file e.g /var/www/html/chrisbodnarchuk.com/log in your virtualHost config, you must touch `/var/www/html/chrisbodnarchuk.com/log/error.log` to avoid error, same for access.log (if any).

> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully
>   qualified domain name, using

To get rid of this error add the following to the top of your configuration:

```
NameVirtualHost localhost
```

You may add the above to your apache.conf

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm wondering if I even needed to install apache2 on my ssh anyhow since apache was already downloaded by root on the linux system. Like it doesnt run because there are two instances of apache or something????

Comment: what is the output of `netstat -plunt |grep -i ":80"`

Comment: when i run this from my not_root ssh i get `(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)` When I run from same ssh with root i get `Kernel Interface table
Iface   MTU Met   RX-OK RX-ERR RX-DRP RX-OVR    TX-OK TX-ERR TX-DRP TX-OVR Flg
eth0       1500 0       443      0      0 0           245      0      0      0 BMRU
lo        65536 0         0      0      0 0             0      0      0      0 LRU`

Comment: It looks like web server is not running .  So you will install it with `apt-get install build-essential apache2 apache2-utils -y` Then restart web server with : `service apache2 restart`

Comment: i should be doing that from the root user in the ssh? Am I understanding correctly by the way that the sshs' apache2 has nothing to do with apache2 on my general linux machine?